# issue with Linked List

Tags: c#, linked-list

i wan to create a linked list that contains the name , age and address of some people , so far i created that code :

```
    LinkedList<string> details = new LinkedList<string>();

    details.AddFirst("Name1");
    details.AddLast("Name2");
    details.AddLast("Name3");

    foreach (var display in details)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(display);
    }
```

ok so now it works fine , but i just input the name , how can i input the age and address , is it like array ? i just don`t know much about linkedlists , and also i tried to delete some nodes of the linkedlist but i failed :

```
    foreach (var item in details)
    {
        if (item.Contains("Name3"))
        {
            details.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

but i get that error :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.
```

and finally , how can i edit a linkedlist item , like renaming Name2 to Name13 or anything , i would really appreciate any help , just give me idea and i`ll continue digging . Thanks in advance .

Comment: you can not add/remove items from a collection in a foreach loop--an exception will be thrown (as you have seen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to add extra information within the list, simply create a class which encapsulates that information, as the `LinkedList` is a generic type. For example:

```
//Structure to hold extra information
public class PersonDetails
{
  public string Name {get; private set;}

  public int Age {get; private set;}

  public string Address {get; private set;}

  //Constructor
  public PersonDetails(string name, int age, string address)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Age = age;
    this.Address = address;
  }
}
```

Then you can create a new linked list containing those types:

```
LinkedList<PersonDetails> list = new LinkedList<PersonDetails>();
list.AddFirst(new PersonDetails("Name", 22, "Address"));
```

Note that you cannot modify a collection when you are enumerating it, you need to perform your check and modify it outside of your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 5):

You can't remove elements from the list while iterating a list using `foreach`  loop.

```
 if (details.Remove("Name3"))
     Console.WriteLine("Removed");
 else
     Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
```

Answer (score 3):

A linked list is like an array in that it is a collection of data. Each item in the list stores a link to the next item (and often the previous), hence the name.

You can't modify a list you're looping over, because your reference into the list will then be invalid.

Comment: The reference to the list isn't invalid... it's just that the enumerator is in an invalid state.

Comment: I didn't mean the list reference, the reference into. i.e. if you delete the item you're currently on, then you're breaking the enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LINQ, you can convert your code to a linq approach such as:

```
details = details.Where(item => !item.Contains("Name3")).ToList();
```